# Ubuntu stucked on splash screen (Can't able to enter on user/password, desktop screen)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-20.04, bad-sectors

I am stuck on how to load completely the OS and the login/password screen, the PC stops on the Ubuntu black screen and stuck on it:

[image]

This is the situation from my HDD in GParted, which seems that everything is ok:

[image]

[image]

And the situation of my disks:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.13 GiB, 2285019136 bytes, 4462928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 61.93 MiB, 64917504 bytes, 126792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 65.22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 54.24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 248.78 MiB, 260841472 bytes, 509456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 43.6 MiB, 45703168 bytes, 89264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 596.18 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Disk model: ST640LM001 HN-M6
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4D164AE1-B36F-4F3F-8525-11EFE9BC7156

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 1250263039 1249212416 595.7G Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/sdb: 14.96 GiB, 16039018496 bytes, 31326208 sectors
Disk model: v165w           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1693364d

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0  6599743  6599744  3.2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       5930192  5938191     8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3       6602752 31326207 24723456 11.8G 83 Linux
```

Is there any idea in how to get the OS back?? I have opened a post before where I removed all the badblocks, now only the OS isn't loading.

Comment: Can you get into grub?

Comment: Yes, I can able to access it normally... I can able to access the grub screen, after, it comes the Ubuntu splash screen with the loading icon for some time and after, this loading icon disappears and it stops

Comment: I am so desperate with it, alternatively I'm watching some videos about methods to recover data from dev/sda2/ in the Live USB

Comment: The next step I would be taking woyld be to edit grub so it does not display the splash screen - that will expose the startup text and could give you a good idea what is failing - once you know this you can then fix it.  That is coveted in https://askubuntu.com/questions/5065/how-can-i-disable-the-purple-splash-screen-at-boot - ie remove "splash quiet" from grub